# Export Excel tabs with the page formatting

Tags: excel, vba

I have working VBA code for exporting all tabs in my workbook as individual sheets named by the tab name.

```vb
Sub split_to_seperate_sheets()
Dim Sheet As Worksheet, SheetName$, MyFilePath$, N&
MyFilePath$ = ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\" & _
Left(ThisWorkbook.Name, Len(ThisWorkbook.Name) - 4)
With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = False
    .DisplayAlerts = False
     '      End With
    On Error Resume Next '<< a folder exists
    MkDir MyFilePath '<< create a folder
    For N = 1 To Sheets.Count
        Sheets(N).Activate
        SheetName = ActiveSheet.Name
        Cells.Copy
        Workbooks.Add (xlWBATWorksheet)
        With ActiveWorkbook
            With .ActiveSheet
                .Paste
                .Name = SheetName
                [A1].Select
        End With
             'save book in this folder
            .SaveAs FileName:="C:\Seasonal Brochures\Price Pages\2022 May\" & SheetName & ".xlsx"
            .Close SaveChanges:=True
        End With
        .CutCopyMode = False
    Next
End With
Sheet1.Activate
End Sub
```

I want to set the page formatting before it saves each new workbook.

I tried to insert the following code.

```vb
    'set page formatting
    With ActiveSheet.PageSetup
        .printArea = "$A$1:$L$32"
        .FitToPagesWide = 1
        .FitToPagesTall = 1
        .Orientation = xlLandscape
    End With
```

Comment: Where/how did you insert the new code?

Comment: When working with worksheets, it is not necessary to `Activate` them. Stop doing that, and just directly address the sheet, as you do with `Sheets[N]`. There is absolutely no reason to activate the sheet or any cells within it before doing something with them. Removing all the calls to `Activate` will most likely improve the performance of your code, as well as making it more readable and maintainable.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the tip.  Honestly, I found the original code somewhere else but now I'm trying to add additional formatting.

Answer (score 0):

I found different VBA code that does the job.

It seems to export the tabs formatted as they are.

```vb
Sub SplitWorkbook()
'Updateby20200806
Dim FileExtStr As String
Dim FileFormatNum As Long
Dim xWs As Worksheet
Dim xWb As Workbook
Dim xNWb As Workbook
Dim FolderName As String
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Set xWb = Application.ThisWorkbook

DateString = Format(Now, "yyyy-mm-dd hh-mm-ss")
FolderName = xWb.Path & "\" & xWb.Name & " " & DateString

If Val(Application.Version) < 12 Then
    FileExtStr = ".xls": FileFormatNum = -4143
Else
    Select Case xWb.FileFormat
        Case 51:
            FileExtStr = ".xlsx": FileFormatNum = 51
        Case 52:
            If Application.ActiveWorkbook.HasVBProject Then
                FileExtStr = ".xlsm": FileFormatNum = 52
            Else
                FileExtStr = ".xlsx": FileFormatNum = 51
            End If
        Case 56:
            FileExtStr = ".xls": FileFormatNum = 56
        Case Else:
            FileExtStr = ".xlsb": FileFormatNum = 50
    End Select
End If

MkDir FolderName

For Each xWs In xWb.Worksheets
    On Error GoTo NErro
    If xWs.Visible = xlSheetVisible Then
    xWs.Select
    xWs.Copy
    xFile = FolderName & "\" & xWs.Name & FileExtStr
    Set xNWb = Application.Workbooks.Item(Application.Workbooks.Count)
    xNWb.SaveAs xFile, FileFormat:=FileFormatNum
    xNWb.Close False, xFile
    End If
NErro:
    xWb.Activate
Next

MsgBox "You can find the files in " & FolderName
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```